# ArrayList<String>.add throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I wrote this code:

```
List<String> doneTiers = new ArrayList<>();
if (ps.getData("achievements.Done") != null) {
    doneTiers = Arrays.asList(ps.getData("achievements.Done").split("/./"));
}
Msg.debug(tier, tier.getName());
doneTiers.add(tier.getName());// dodany
ps.setData("achievements.Done", DataUTIL.format(doneTiers, "/./"));
```

and I have error in this line `doneTiers.add(tier.GetName());`

[image: UnsupportedOperationException]

Answer (score 3):

[`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) creates a fixed-size list, so once created, you cannot add more elements to it. Since you already initialized `doneTiers` with `new ArrayList<>()`, you can use `addAll` like this:

```
doneTiers.addAll(Arrays.asList(ps.getData("achievements.Done").split("/./")))
```

Comment: hmm ah ok but how to create List from splited string? like this?
for(String str : ps.getData("achivemenets.Done").split("/./")){
doneTiers.add(str);
}
?

Comment: You're welcome! Little hint: if you like the answer, hit the big tick mark to the left of it to mark it as "accepted".